# should I use a database or string.xml for port mapping data

Tags: android, android-resources, android-database

I have a file containing port mappings in the following format.

```
spr-itunes        0/tcp    Shirt Pocket netTunes
spl-itunes        0/tcp    Shirt Pocket launchTunes
tcpmux            1/tcp    TCP Port Service Multiplexer
```

It goes all the way to 1024. These are the well known ports. The app i'm working on scan a particular host for these ports. And cross reference with this file to get information on a particular port eg: type of service running, protocol info. But I don't know what is the proper way to store this file. Should I create a database eg db file or should I add them to Strings.xml or maybe just as a regular file and load the file into memory when program runs. This last one I think is too memory consuming. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Or even SharedPreferences... A database seems an overkill, for so little data.

Comment: so this file is created and populated when the app starts and then it can be accessed through the life of the app? That's what I understood from developers reference. But it doesn't say where to store in the project structure. I have to copy the file, read from it, then create sharePreference which I can use. Is this correct?

Comment: No. It's managed by Android itself. You shouldn't even care for where it is. It will be created in the app data space. Then you can use it for as long the app is on your device. It also survives app upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But is there an easier way to populate this file (sharedpreference) that doesn't involved hardcoding 1024 lines of port mappings into the app. Can I copy the text file as resource into the app and read from it and then populate sharedpreference. But this way seems redundant operation. Thanks

Comment: Well, you showed only 3 lines and didn't tell that you needed 1024 lines. In that case, I'd use a database, instead. And importing a CSV file line by line in a for loop is a trivial task.

Comment: why do I have to import the file. can I just create a databse/csv file and access the file as a query looking for whatever piece of info I'm looking for

Comment: Yes, that would be even better. Make a prefilled database and simply use it in your app.